# Ограждение тестовых сайтов клиентов от индексации

Tags: nginx, индексация

Здравствуйте други админы.
Нужен мозговой штурм.
Есть несколько сайтов с доменом третьего уровня на моем домене, это тестовые сайты для клиентов. 
Задача такая: ограничить доступ так, чтобы на определенный сайт могли попасть только определенные люди, при этом сайты не индексировались нигде в поисковиках и не отображались.

Какие есть предложения в реализации?

PS используется только NGINX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Авторизация через `mod_auth_digest`

Comment: О. круто. спасибо. это подошло бы. есть мануал хороший чтобы изучить?

Comment: Нашел, реализовал. спасибо огромное. [вот отличный мануал](https://www.8host.com/blog/nastrojka-http-avtorizacii-nginx-v-ubuntu-12-10/)

Answer (score 2):

Так что именно нужно сделать? Запретить индексацию или сделать доступ только для определённых людей?

Если хотите просто запретить индексацию роботами - то можно использовать файл `robots.txt`, размещённый в корне сайта, с таким содержимым:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Если хотите сделать это через nginx - то можно сделать ограничения по идентификатору:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (перечень|user|agent) ) {
  return 403;
}
```

Если же нужно разрешить вход на сайт только с определёных адресов, то сделайте так:

```
server {
      listen ...;
      server_name ...;
      allow 1.1.1.1;
      allow 9.8.7.6;
      allow 73.23.41.98;
      deny all;
      ...
}
```

Comment: robots.txt GOOGLE игнорирует. в этом вся проблема...

Comment: @АнаньевСергей: почему GOOGLE может проиндексировать страницу несмотря на файл robots.txt описано в документации Google - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru. Что бы этого избежать надо использовать метатег robots или заголовок X-Robots-Tag. Например - `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`. Примеры и значения тут - https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag

Comment: Да. я знаю но это не удобно, т.к. при выхождении проекта из тестового этапа, все эти тэги придется удалять.